# I want to order my crew to disassemble C2-N2, but the intercom doesn't seem to do anything at all

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When you get your ship in SW:TOR my experience has been that there is a droid on board who is exceedingly annoying. One supposedly useful thing you are told though is that there is an intercom that "...will inform your crew that you wish to issue new orders." However I have yet to notice any effect when clicking it (right or left!).  Does the intercom actually do anything? If not are there rumors or expectations as to what is likely to be implemented for it functionally wise?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Intercom, Holocommunicator, and the Escape Pod are all class-quest specific items that only have interactions when you're on a quest that requires interacting with them.

In the meantime, they're vaguely glow-y flavor for your ship.

Alas, C2-N2 will have to remain your as he is.

Comment: am I weird that I actually like C2-N2?  I even use it to fight when I need a healer companion

Comment: @Rodolfo Yes you are :P

Comment: @Rodolfo: I can confirm this. You are weird for liking C2-N2. Or possibly you don't play with the voiceovers enabled.

Comment: awww, poor C2, he's so misunderstood.
But honestly, it's a good healer until you get your real companion healer, and when he's an active companion, he doesn't even talk :)

Comment: If you're visiting another player's ship, you can use the escape pod to return to the planet.

Comment: @Rodolfo he's always got my best interests at heart, piling cushion above cushion on the pilot chairs, and my respiratory health has never been so fine!